# Running ID based on 2 columns

Tags: sql

Can someone help. Been trawling through Google and loads of forums but can't seem to find what I am looking for. I need some kind of running ID added to my data. See example below.

This is my data

| ID | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 | WP1234 | C |
| 2 | 22 | WP1235 | C |
| 3 | 22 | WP1236 | O |
| 4 | 24 | WP1237 | C |
| 5 | 24 | WP1238 | C |
| 6 | 24 | WP1239 | O |
| 7 | 26 | WP1240 | C |
| 8 | 26 | WP1241 | C |
| 9 | 28 | WP1242 | C |

I need to get some kind of running ID based on columns and A, C.

Desired outcome would be

| ID | A | B | C | RunningID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 | WP1234 | C | 1 |
| 2 | 22 | WP1235 | C | 2 |
| 3 | 22 | WP1236 | O | 1 |
| 4 | 24 | WP1237 | C | 1 |
| 5 | 24 | WP1238 | C | 2 |
| 6 | 24 | WP1239 | O | 1 |
| 7 | 26 | WP1240 | C | 1 |
| 8 | 26 | WP1241 | C | 2 |
| 9 | 28 | WP1242 | C | 1 |

Comment: So you want an ID for each row with the same A and C? Yes this exists but I think the syntax is database-dependent. Which database?

Comment: (whoops, sorry, I'd meant to comment not edit)

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? It's important for us to know that if you need help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by a, c order by id) as running_id
from t;
```